# Find the sum of all numbers between 1 and N divisible by either x or y

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, puzzle

Say we have `3` numbers `N`, `x` and `y` which are always `>=1`.

N will be greater than `x` and `y` and `x` will be greater than `y`.

Now we need to **find the sum of all number between 1 and N that are divisible by either x or y**.

I came up with this:

```
sum = 0;
for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
{
  if(i%x || i%y)
    sum += i;
}
```

Is there a way better way of finding the sum avoiding the for loop?

I've been pounding my head for many days now but have not got anything better.

If the value of `N` has a upper limit we can use a lookup method to speedup the process.

Thanks everyone.

I wanted a C/C++ based solution. Is there a built-in function to do this? Or do I have to code the algorithm?

Comment: Even if it is homework, at least s/he gave us a solution that s/he worked on. S/he's looking for, maybe, something better.

Comment: I feel like this is related to the trick for finding primes but I can't dredge it out of my memory yet

Comment: @user545682 (or any editor) -- kindly give a more descriptive title, as this is an interesting topic that should be decently searchable.

Comment: your condition should be `if (i % x == 0 || i % y == 0) sum += i;` or it'll calculate the sum of numbers that aren't either a multiple of x or y

Answer (score 27):

Yes. You can void the for loop altogether and find the sum in constant time.

According to the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion_principle) summing up the multiples of `x` and multiples of `y` and subtracting the common multiple(s) that got added *twice* should give us the required sum.

```
Required Sum = sum of ( multiples of x that are <= N ) +      
               sum of ( multiples of y that are <= N ) -
               sum of ( multiples of (x*y) that are <= N )
```

Example:

```
N = 15
x = 3
y = 4

Required sum = ( 3 + 6 + 9 + 12 + 15) +  // multiples of 3
               ( 4 + 8 + 12 ) -          // multiples of 4
               ( 12 )                    // multiples of 12
```

As seen above we had to subtract `12` as it got added twice because it is a common multiple.

**How is the entire algorithm O(1)?**

Let `sum(x, N)` be sum of multiples of `x` which are less than or equal to `N`.

```
sum(x,N) = x + 2x + ... + floor(N/x) * x
         = x * ( 1 + 2 + ... + floor(N/x) )
         = x * ( 1 + 2 + ... + k)    // Where k = floor(N/x)
         = x * k * (k+1) / 2         // Sum of first k natural num = k*(k+1)/2
```

Now `k = floor(N/x)` can be computed in constant time.

Once `k` is known `sum(x,N)` can be computed in constant time.

So the required sum can also be computed in constant time.

**EDIT:**

The above discussion holds true only when `x` and `y` are [co-primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime). If not we need to use `LCM(x,y)` in place of `x*y`. There are many ways to find LCM one of which is to divide product by GCD. Now GCD cannot be computed in constant time but its [**time complexity**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Complexity) can be made significantly lesser than linear time.

Comment: Wow!!Thank you for making it so clear. It looks so simple now.

Comment: Nice answer!  One problem, though.  If `x` is a multiple of `y`, you only do the first step.

Comment: Nice answer - but you need to use the LCM (lowest common multiple), not `x*y`. For example, if the numbers are 4 and 6, then 12 will get counted twice, but in this case `x*y` is 24. And unfortunately the LCM can't be calculated in constant time, but it *can* be calculated very quickly.

Comment: please can you fix your answer - the `x*y` issue means it will sometimes give the wrong answer :-(. For example, `x=4`, `y=6`, `N=12`. Clearly the here answer is `4+6+8+12=30`; your answer will give `(4+8+12)+(6+12)-(0)=42` when it should give `(4+8+12)+(6+12)-(12)=30` - as I mentioned, using the lowest common multiple `LCM(4,6)=12` is crucial here.

Comment: @psmears: Thanks a lot for noticing the bug :)

Answer (score 4):

If a number is divisible by X, it has to be a multiple of x.
If a number is divisible by Y, it has to be a multiple of y.

I believe, if you do a for loop for all multiples of x and y, and avoid any duplicates, you should get the same answer.

Out of my head, something of the type:

```
sum = 0
for( i=x; i<=n; i+=x)
    sum += i;

for( i=y; i<=n; i+=y)
    if( y % x != 0 )
        sum += i;
```

Comment: +1 - beat me to it. Multiples will require fewer comparison operations (although whether or not its actually faster is a different story).

Comment: @Tim -- as N approaches infinity, I'm sure such a solution gets faster =)